# Unable to decrease the width on using mediaqueries to contact form

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Created a contact form. For making it responsive, i have added a mediquery at 768px to decrease the width of the input field. But it ain't changing.

I will attach the code below for your reference

```
<div class="form-container">
    <h1>send us a message</h1>
    <form class="form">
      <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name">
      <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail">
      <textarea id="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
      <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i>SEND</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

I used SCSS to style my contact form...

```
.form-container {
  margin: 6rem 0;
  height: auto;

  h1 {
    color: $header-main;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: $primary-font;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-size: 2.3rem;
    letter-spacing: 1px;

    &:after {
      @include shortBorder(10rem, 1rem, 3px, #111);
      margin-bottom: 5rem;
    }
  }


  .form {
    input[type="text"],
    textarea,button {
      display: block; 
      margin: 2rem auto;
      width: 600px;
      padding: 1rem;
      border-radius: 1rem;
      border: 1px solid $plane-white;
      box-shadow: 2px 3px 3px 3px #ccc;
      outline: none;
      transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
    }

    input:hover,
    textarea:hover {
      width: 620px;
    }


    ::placeholder { 
      color: rgb(155, 148, 146);
      font-weight: 900;
      font-family: 'Roboto';
    }

    button {
      background-color: $header-main;
      color: $plane-white;
      width: 140px;
      box-shadow: none;
      i {
        margin-right: 0.5rem;
      }
    }
  }

  button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 160px;
  }
}
```

Media query on contact form.. should decrease to 500px from 600px.

```
@mediaqueries screen and (max-width:768px) {
    .form {
    width: 500px;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of things stopping inputs from shrinking.

1. You have set rows & columns as size parameters on your text area. 
   `<textarea id="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Message"></textarea>`
   This acts as width & height in the HTML. You should remove this and set it with CSS.
2. Depending on the [`box-model`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) you're using, `margin` & `padding` may be ADDING to the overall width of your elements.
3. Your media queries aren't targeting the correct elements so it's not being applied as you expect.

Base CSS: (you're changing the width of inputs INSIDE a `.form`)

```
.form input[type="text"], 
.form textarea,
.form button {
    width: 600px;
}
```

media query (**you're changing the form, not the inputs**)

```
.form {
    width: 500px;
}
```